# ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I have this warning, Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated
someone please help me.

ereg_replace:

```
ereg_replace('([^(folder)])/images/flash', '"/folder/images/flash', $echotemp);
```

to preg_replace:

Comment: Well, you can start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), and especially [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php).

Comment: What language is this? Add this info if you want more specific answers, it'll help your question visibility

Comment: What do you think `([^(folder)])` means within a regex?

Answer (score 0):

A deprecated method is a method that will in the future be dropped out of the language you're using. Unless you've got control on the language specifications and roadmap, you don't have much leverage.

You can still use the method, but it can disappear in a future update, and usually support about the method will just recommend switching to the new recommended ways of doing things.

I recommend using the replacement method for ereg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

From: [ereg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php/)

> Note: 
>   As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension is deprecated in favor of the [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) extension. Calling this function will issue an E_DEPRECATED notice. See [the list of differences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) for help on converting to PCRE.

.

> Tip
>
> preg_replace(), which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression syntax, is often a faster alternative to ereg_replace().

Read: [PCRE regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

---

And for your pattern:

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).
>
> If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash. If the delimiter appears often inside the pattern, it is a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to increase readability. 
>   So, your pattern should look like:

`([^(folder)])/images/flash`
[] that you have use in [^(folder)] is for specifying character-set and not a whole word. Its better to use simple patterns and not complicate a search pattern.

`%^/folder/images/flash%`
This is more simple.
`I am using % as delimiter for readability.` Not using # because stackoverflow will treat it as a heading :P.